# Does Search API index custom fields?

Tags: 8, search

I am using search API on my website (Version 1.8), I have a problem with indexing custom fields. In the Configuration -> Search and metadata -> Search API I have added the custom fields to be indexed, in the view in the "Fulltext search" the custom fields appeared. In the database I can see that the fields got indexed. But when I test, there is no result. Has anyone had similar troubles with Search API?

Edited: The problem occurs only with the fields of "Entity reference" type

Comment: `The problem occurs only with the fields of "Entity reference" type` well that's because entity reference fields are saved as id's (numbers and not text) in the database. So if you were to search by id it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but most obviously the users will search other users by names, not by ids. I am searching for some additional module, which could map ids with the names.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to index the referenced entity Name* (assuming you want to search on name) as a field instead of just simply the entity ID (which is what entity reference fields actually store). The pattern should look something like the following on the 'fields' page:

`field_yourfield:entity:name`

Comment: I am doing that, but not working. Have indexed field_contact:entity:name , made "Fulltext" type, but no result.

Comment: Down on the page there is a note: The following fields cannot be indexed since there is no type mapping for them:

Comment: Hm I would say forget the fulltext and just try as a string (no need for fulltext with an entity name). What exactly is the entity reference to? Sounds like maybe it’s users?

Comment: yes, exactly. I have a custom field_contact field. And I need to implement search by contact. So in the interface i picked field_contact:entity:name but getting abovementioned message